# Show that $X $ is a infinite set ,it is connected in the finite complement topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

what i had done :let X be a infinite set and there be open sets $A,B$ on it. such that $A\cap B =\varnothing$ or $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$then  $X-A\cap X-B \ne  \varnothing $ .which means there doesn't exist   $X-A\cap X-B = \varnothing $ ,which implies that there is no separation of X in finite complement topology. is this proof correct.

Comment: Why do you write $A\cap B = \emptyset$ or $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$? both can't be true.

Comment: You should be using $\varnothing$ or $\emptyset$, not $\phi$.

Comment: i am taking one case at a time @rise

Answer (score 3):

If $A \subset X$ is clopen in the cofinite topology, then ($A = \varnothing$ or $X - A$ is finite) and ($X - A = \varnothing$ or $A$ is finite).

Studying the four cases, we find only two possibilities: $A = \varnothing$ or $A = X$. This means that the only clopen sets are $\varnothing$ and $X$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $X$ were disconnected-so we can write $X = A \cup B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$, with neither $A,B = \emptyset$.

Now if $T$ is our entire space, $A \cap B = \emptyset$ means $(A \cap B)^c = \emptyset^c = T$.

That is, $A^c \cup B^c = T$. But $X \subseteq T$, so $T$ is infinite, but $A^c \cup B^c$ is finite, contradiction.

Thus $X$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is not connected then non-empty disjoint closed sets $F,G$ exist with $X=F\cup G$.

Now note that $F$ and $G$ are both finite, hence $X$ is finite.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathcal{T}_f=\{U\mid X-U\space\text{is finite or all of}\space X\}$

Suppose $A,B$ are two separation of $X$. Let $V$ is a open set and $V\subset A$, then $X-U\supset B$. Now note that $X-U$ is **finite** and $B$ is **infinite**, which contradicts our assumption on $X$. Hence *finite complement topology* is connected.$\space\space\space\space\space\space\blacksquare$